# Excel Sumif Drag not taking the proper values

Tags: excel, function

I have an issue in dragging the sumif formula.

I have used the formula:

```
=sumif(sheet1!$R$R,Sheet2!$A$3,sheet1!T:T)+ sumif(sheet1!$R$R,Sheet2!$A$3,sheet1!U:U)
```

This gives the sum of consecutive cells .When I drag the formula only the first cell is taking the proper value remaining taking the duplicates of the previous one.

Comment: are your calcs set to Manual?  Try hitting F9.

Comment: Which way are you dragging, and what do you expect the formula to become? If you're dragging across, the T:T will become U:U and the U:U will become V:V, nothing else will change.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a fixed reference to sum these. Try removing the dollar signs from the second argument:

=sumif(sheet1!$R$R,**Sheet2!$A$3**,sheet1!T:T)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

=SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$19,Sheet2!$B3,Sheet1!$D$3:$D$18)+SUMIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$19,Sheet2!$B3,Sheet1!$E$3:$E$18)

This is the code which Used , Issue with this is not getting value across and also downwards values are not correct.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70337397/edit) the question to add information. Don't post part of your question as an answer.